# Are these all possible kernels of a surjection between abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}/a_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/a_n \mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}/b_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/b_n \mathbb{Z}$ be finite abelian groups, written in elementary divisor form, meaning $a_i \mid a_{i+1}$ and $b_i \mid b_{i+1}$ for all $i$.  Suppose $\varphi: A \to B$ is a surjection. Is $\ker(\varphi)$ necessarily of the form $\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}/k_i \mathbb{Z}$ where $k_i=a_i/b_{\pi(i)}$ for some permutation $\pi$?

Comment: Do you mean this form effectively as a subgroup within $A$, or only up to isomorphism? For the former, the answer is *no*, consider $+:\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: I mean up to isomorphism.

Comment: Then I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Is there a reason for $b_{\pi(i)}\mid a_i$? And why a permutation? Likely the divisibility starts from some index on.